Is there any way to drop _in place_ duplicated column _names_ in Pandas?
The accent of this question is on the words names and in place, because I want to drop columns having equal names (no matter the values) but I don't want to drop columns having equal values but different names, and I want do it efficiently.
In other words I'm searching for an in place version of df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()] to avoid the temporary copy of the dataframe.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0],[1, 2, 3, 1, 1], [2, 3, 4, 2, 2]], columns=iter('ABCAD'))

# expected result
print(df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()])

The rationale is cleaning large dataframes.

This shouldn't be an issue with the copy-on-Write mechanism that will only make a copy when data is assigned (will be a default in pandas 3).
If you really want a workaround, you could always rename the columns in place (with set_axis) before dropping the "duplicates" in place:
old_cols = df.columns
new_cols = pd.io.common.dedup_names(df.columns, False)
df = df.set_axis(new_cols, axis=1, copy=False)
df.drop(columns=old_cols.symmetric_difference(new_cols), inplace=True)

